# Placing affiliation in footnote without using \thanks

Tags: footnotes, affiliation, authblk, wlscirep

This is my first message. I have tried over multiple days to find a way to place affiliations and corresponding authorship for a Journal manuscript using wlscirep.cls in the footnotes, while keeping the author bloc visually unchanged. So far I have not found any satisfactory way of doing so, even using \thanks. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{wlscirep}
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\captionsetup{font=normalsize}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalsize}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[pscoord]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\usepackage{authblk}
\makeatletter
\let\@fnsymbol\@arabic
\makeatother

\title{My title}
\begin{document}

\author[1,*]{John Doe}
\author[2]{John Smith}
\author[2]{An Author}
\author[1]{Another Author}

\affil[*]{Life University}
\affil[2]{Other University}
\affil[*]{Corresponding author}

\maketitle\thispagestyle{fancy}

Text
\end{document}
```

Since this is my first message on this forum, please let me know if there is anything I did wrong in this request, so that I may improve.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The document class `wlscirep` isn't on ctan, so it would be helpful if you said where it can be found.

Comment: Hi, the document class is provided by Overleaf using the template for scientific reports found following the link: https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns

Comment: So you want the footnotes at the bottom of the page and not at the bottom of the author block, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct